# TextField's current focus position in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-textinputfield

Hey I have a TextField and a controller for it through which I access its current text value and add some text like (**Some Special Asterix or text with angular brackets just like hashnode's text editor**) to it when needed, adding text at the end is easy.

```
controller.text += "Something";
```

The above code will add Something to the end. But I need to know the current TextFields Cursor position and add text according to it.
I really love to know how we can do it in flutter efficiently

Comment: Why not just use `controller.text.length`?

Comment: I am more eager to know why cursor position is important in this scenario, could you put some light on it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the cursor position

```
print(controller.selection.baseOffset);
print(controller.selection.extentOffset);
```

if they are the same, it is current cursor position.
if not, it means that some of text is selected, `baseOffset` is start position and `extentOffset` is end positon.

Comment: He's not asking for putting the cursor at the end of the line/text

Comment: @iDecode Sorry, I should check it carefully. I have updated my answer